# Firebase list query (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, social-networking

I am currently building a small social app with Firebase as my back end. I am able to load a list of posts from various users based on queries related to the posts like date posted, topic, etc. My issue is I want to load only posts from users that are being followed by the one using the app. I've been searching for a few days, but don't exactly know what to search for or where to start.

Comment: simply query it using where clause and find the followers , i hope u have something related to followers linked to every user

Comment: @PavneetSingh yes each user object has a list of followers, but was not sure exactly how to shape a query based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Firebase documentation about how to [structure your database.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). You can store a list of each user's follower's ids in that user's profile object, and then load posts only from those follower ids.